# OSB - Importing config jar into a lower version of weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, osb

I have created OSB project in Oracle Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2 and when I tried to import that config jar into weblogic server 12.2.1.0 , I was getting "Invalid config jar" error. When I migrated that project to Jdeveloper 12.2.1.0 and imported that config jar in the same version, its working. Is it an expected scenario ? If I want to develop on 12.2.1.2 and deploy that jar in 12.2.1.0 server how should I create the jar compatible to a lower version of weblogic ?

Comment: Have you tried opening up the jar and finding references to the string "12.2.1.2" and changing them to "12.2.1.0"?

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I updated the version info in the Export Info file of the config jar and it is working .

Comment: I updated the version in the config jar manually. Is there a way I can specify the product version at the time of jar creation itself ?? I am creating the jar through configjar tool that comes with jdeveloper

Comment: This trick does not work for my 12.2.1.3.0 sbar.

Comment: @KarelHusa its working fine, open the ExportInfo and update the product version number, then check the file is updated right, and then try to deploy. it should be ok.

Comment: @LiorA you are right, when I extracted the archive and zipped again, I got an error. If I only update the archive, it works.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you can't alter the product version during the creation of the config jar. You can, however, put an additional step after creation to modify the config after it's created - either before you put into a repo, or just before deploying to a particular environment if you want to customise it beyond the (meagre) capabilities of the ALSB customisation file.

My go-to tool is [Configurator](https://github.com/tomecode/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator/), which you would need to fork and write an extra feature to update the product version, but if that doesn't appeal you can write some code to unjar the file and alter the value yourself before jarring it again.